# "Fall term", "autumn semester", "autumn term" or "fall semester"?

Tags: american-english, british-english, collocation

Please clarify which is UK English, American English, and where and when to use which:

- *Fall term* (American English?)
- *Autumn semester* (UK English?)
- *Autumn term* (wrong?)
- *Fall semester* (wrong?)

Comment: Are you talking about university or high school?

Answer (score 6):

*Fall* and *autumn* are famous differences between British and American use, both recognised in all forms of English, but *fall* almost never actually used in Britain and Ireland and rarely in Australia or New Zealand, *autumn* almost never used in America, and Canada using both.

*Term* and *semester* are not strict synonyms. *Term* applies to any part the academic year is broken into, while *semester* strictly applies only to a bipartite system, with *trimester* (yes, the same as pregnant ladies have) for a tripartite and *quadmester* or *quarter* for a quadripartite system (such as Australian schools have).

To add confusion, if you have three normal terms, but also offer supplementary classes over the summer, then the terms can be referred to both as *trimesters* (taking the name from the three only) and as *quarters* (taking the name from all four).

Not long ago you could be pretty confident that a given US college or university would use semesters and a given UK or Irish one would use trimesters. In the last few decades though, many UK & Irish colleges introduced a policy of *semesterisation* (such a cumbersome word to put on posters at Student Union protests, but put it on, we did) and now have semesters while some US colleges have three-term or three-terms-with-supplementary-summer-term systems.

Since they aren't perfect synonyms, there are times when precision leads to US speakers using *term* or UK speakers using *semester* or *trimester* as appropriate. At times when one could choose freely between them, a US speaker is more likely to use *semester* while a UK speaker to use *term*. However students or faculty at UK colleges with semesters are slightly more likely to use that term, given its novelty to the college and that the move toward semesters was a controversial one in many colleges, resulting in the word being strong in people's minds. It is also common for such UK colleges to call them *semesters* in timetables and official literature, but people refer to them as *terms* informally.

The names of individual terms in the UK & Ireland differ from college to college. For those with semesters either *Autumn* and *Spring* or *Autumn* and *Spring and Summer* are common, or they might just be *Semester 1 & Semester 2*. For those with trimesters, some examples include:

*Michaelmas, Lent & Easter; Michaelmas, Epiphany & Easter; Michaelmas, Lent & Summer; Autumn, Spring & Summer; Michaelmas, Hilary & Trinity; Martinmas, Candlemas  & Whitsunday*.

Traditionally, the English split the year into *Hilary, Easter, Trinity & Michaelmas* with Ireland following suit (in some ways the history of Trinity College Dublin is as much a British one as an Irish), while the Scots split it into *Candlemas, Whitsunday, Lammas  & Martinmas*. As they each altered their systems in different ways at different times, they ended up having different names from each other.

These sometimes survive into semester names, with e.g. St. Andrews having *Martinmas & Candlemas* semesters, due to their once having a trimester system with the terms named, *Martinmas, Candlemas & Whitsunday*.

---

Edit,  mplungjan's comment makes me consider that some of these names may be unfamiliar to some.

**Easter**: Probably known to all, but included for completeness. The movable feast of the resurrection of Christ. First sunday after first full moon, after 21 March, it can be anywhere between 22 March and 25 April.

**Lent**: The forty days before Easter.

**Michaelmas**: Feast of St. Michael the Archangel, 29 September.

**Epiphany**: Feast of the revelation of God made flesh through Christ, and the recongition of this by the magi. January 6.

**Hilary**: Feast of St. Hilary of Poitiers, 13 January.

**Whitsunday**: Generally means the celebration of Pentecost (descent of the Holy Spirit upon the apostles) celebrated on the seventh Sunday after Easter. In Scotland, there was a period when it also refered to a fixed holiday, 15 May.

**Trinity**: Trinity Sunday is the first Sunday after Pentecost.

**Lammas**: Feast of St. Peter in chains. August 1, combined in Britain with the Anglo-Saxon *hlaf-mas* (loaf mass) and absorbing the Lughnasadh of Scotland, Ireland and Man.

**Martinmas**: Feast of St. Martin of Tours, 11 November.

Comment: PS: For those who wonder about Hilary: _The Hilary sessions of British High Court and universities (1577) are from St. Hilarius, Bishop of Poitiers, obit. C.E. 368, whose feast day is Jan. 13._

Comment: @mplungjan actually, Whitsunday may be the more confusing, since the Scots use it slightly differently to most. I shall add a bit on the name origins.

Comment: *Autumn* is catching on in the US though.  So much less cumbersome than having to use the definite article with a season.  Oh, and *fall* doesn't give you *autumnal*.

Comment: @Jez you'll find occasional use of *Fall* over here. Still so rare as to count as "hardly ever" though. Both words have some great poetic qualities in their favour (as does *Harvest* which was the most common term up until the 1700s). Besides, while *fall* doesn't give you *autumnal*, nor does *spring* give you *vernal*, but we still use it.

Answer (score 2):

American usage for September to December in this context is "Fall", never "Autumn". [Correction: a commenter who did more work with Google has found counterexamples. *Fall* is more common, but not universal] Term is apparently used at [Harvard](http://www.registrar.fas.harvard.edu/calendar/five-year-calendar)  and [Princeton](http://registrar.princeton.edu/events/), but I believe Semester (for a term of approximately 15 weeks) and Quarter (for a term of approximately 10 weeks) are more common. Not all our universities are so long in the tooth!

[Berkeley](http://registrar.berkeley.edu/CalendarDisp.aspx?terms=current) [Semester];
[UCLA](http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/calendar/acadcal11.htm) [Quarter];
[Chicago](http://www.uchicago.edu/academics/calendar/) [Quarter].

I defer to UK readers for usage there.

Comment: Except for Chicago, DePaul, Stanford, U. Washington, and Denver, which all have "autumn quarters", and  Ohio State, which has "autumn semesters", as well as all the U.S. schools which have "autumn terms" (these are harder to find by Googling because so many non-U.S. schools also have "autumn terms"). From this random sample, it seems "autumn" is used more in the Midwest and West than in the East and South. I wonder whether this is statistical fluctuation or a real regional difference in usage.

Comment: Never is clearly too strong. _Fall_ is more common.

Answer (score 1):

The British equivalent of American *semester* is *term*.  Schools have an Autumn Term, a Spring Term and a Summer Term. The University of Oxford has a Michaelmas Term (autumn), a Hilary Term (spring) and a Trinity Term (summer).

Comment: And a bleak midwinter, if I remember correctly. But perhaps your college had modern central heating.

Comment: Semester is becoming more common a term in British universities too, though term is the normal form.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. Central heating? We had to rub two sticks together to make a fire to put the kettle on.

Comment: @nicodemus13 *semester* is becoming a more common term in British universities, because semesters are becoming more common. They aren't synonyms, and *semester* only applies if there are two in the year, while British Universities used to all have trimesters, and many still do.

Comment: Yes, you have to define terms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth LOL. done :)

Answer (score 1):

*Term* is the hypernym in this context. University calendars are typically based on a quarter (10-week) or semester (15-week) system. At either institution, though, the expression *winter term* could be used when referencing the *winter quarter* or the *winter semester*.

Some universities might offer courses in a condensed format over the summer, in which case, you might hear a professor say something like, "I'm only teaching in the second short term this summer."

*Term* can also be used in the context of elementary and secondary education: "My daughter got a B in science last term."

From NOAD:

> **term** (*n*.)  each of the periods in the year, alternating with holidays or vacations, during which instruction is given in a school, college, or university